# Native Apple Maps UIWebView referal

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, maps

Firstly, I posted this because all the other tutorials don't work.
Ok so this is my HTML code

`<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=1/76+Ferry+Rd,+Southport&saddr=Current+Location">Directions</a>`

And I have this as well

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[request.URL description] hasPrefix:@"http://maps"])
        // open URL in Safari and return NO to prevent UIWebView from load it
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    };
```

But everytime I click the link above it redirects me to google maps on the UIWebView but I want it to redirect me to the (Apple) Maps app.

Comment: Check here may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521689/open-ios6-apple-maps-app-from-a-link-in-a-uiwebview

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre I already viewed this and it didnt work for me, it just leads straight back to google, plus I need more than one link, I need a ton (like over 9,000)

Comment: I'd be interested in solving this issue as well. The weirdest thing is that the link works correctly from mobile safari (opens Apple maps), but not from a webview within an app (links to a web version of Google maps).

Answer (score 0):

It will in open apple map app in device

```
    NSString *ll = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",latitude,longitude];
    ll = [ll stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@", ll];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Comment: Can i open this url in uiwebview ?