# Phonegap - Open Navigation Directions in Apple Maps App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, maps

I have two variables - Destination and Source - and, using Phonegap, I'm trying to use jQuery to open the external iPhone Apple Maps app with directions.

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
var url = 'http://maps.apple.com/?q=daddr='+destination+'&saddr='+source;
window.location = url;
```

Whenever I click the relevant button however, it opens a new view in-app with Google directions as a webview, and I cannot return to the original app.

How can link be opened instead with the iOS default map application?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504294/programmatically-open-maps-app-in-ios-6

Comment: I saw that but unfortunately I'm coding with Phonegap in HTML and Javascript so Objective-C isn't the language I'm using to compile - but I've found the solution I needed, thanks for your help!

Comment: @BenPearlKahan I have the same problem, can you show me your soluction? Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Changing `http://maps.apple.com/?q=` to just `maps:` did the trick.

---

NB: make sure you write `maps:` and not `map:` as, while the latter will run the correct app, it will crash immediately after opening (thanks jprofitt)

Comment: Ah-hah! I was wondering if there was something just like that (a specific protocol handler) but hadn't found any documentation - didn't think to just try that! Thanks for posting that.

Comment: Pleasure - was a relief to figure it out!

Comment: Interesting how this is in direct contradiction to Apple's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html but this answer is what works!

Comment: As a note for anyone who gets stuck on trying to figure this out: on iOS 7, if you use `map:` instead of `maps:`, it will in fact launch the Maps app, but will crash immediately. Check your spelling. (Ben, feel free to add this to your answer if you'd like)

Comment: @BenPearlKahan This works, but how can I pass latitude and longitude instead of a name? I was using http://maps.apple.com/maps?ll=51.83733,-8.3016

Answer (score 6):

Today I was able to open the native Apple Maps app with marker from a Cordova app using BOTH of the follow URL schemes:

```
maps://maps.apple.com/?q={latitude},{longitude}
```

AND

```
maps://?q={latitude},{longitude}
```

In a link:

```
<a href="maps://maps.apple.com?q={latitude},{longitude}">
<!-- OR -->
<a href="maps://?q={latitude},{longitude}">
```

From JavaScript:

```
window.location.href = "maps://maps.apple.com/?q="+lat+","+lng;
// OR
window.location.href = "maps://?q="+lat+","+lng;
```

The app is running on an iOS device, iOS version 8.1.2, and cordova-ios is version 3.7.0.

Comment: Not working in iOS 12.3 Cordova 9, Any idea please!!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, changing from `http://maps.apple.com/?q=` to only `maps:?q=` not solving the problem.

The working scheme that open native Apple Maps with marker is as follows:

```
maps://maps.apple.com/?q={latitude},{longitude}
```

full working code:

```
window.location.href = "maps://maps.apple.com/?q="+lat+","+lng;
```

Tested working with iOS7.1 simulator, might not works in later version. I don't have the opportunity to test. Sorry.

Supported Apple Maps parameters can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Credit goes to this SO link: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742040/1023327)

Answer (score 4):

## The code

I managed to get this working in 2018 on iOS 11.2 using the following format in iOS:

```
<a onclick="window.open('maps://?q=51.178847,-1.826160', '_system');">Open in Maps</a>
```

And this format on Android:

```
<a onclick="window.open('geo:0,0?q=51.178847,-1.826160', '_system');">Open in Maps</a>
```

## Config permissions

Additionally, don't forget to add permissions to your `config.xml` file like so:

```
<allow-intent href="maps:*" />
```

In my project the `geo:` intention had existed from the beginning so it took my a while to figure out why this was working on Android and not iOS.

Comment: Not working in iOS 12.3 Cordova 9, Any idea please!!

Comment: Works like a charm on iOS 12.4 Cordova 6.1.1 and Android 30 Cordova 8.0