# how to use maps: in phonegap ios application

Tags: ios, html, cordova

With reference to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504346/1956942)

I'm trying to locate given location onto the native iOS map with the following url :

```
window.location = "maps:Greensboro+NC"
```

But, It opens the map with my current location not the location specified.

Please suggest what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Just check with `window.location = "maps:Greensboro"`

Comment: no, still the same result :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but according to Apple documentation you need a url in the following format:

http://maps.apple.com/?q=Greensboro+NC