# How to add apple map marker via query string in the url?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-maps

I want add map marker (like google map) in the map app when I use a url link to open the map on the iPhone from my app.

like this : `<a href="http://maps.apple.com?ll=latitude,longtitude">`

I can open the apple map and the map center is on the location I want, but how to add a marker at the same time? I am not sure how query string I can add on the url

I have already read the doc below

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I add the code now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanna use internal map app (Apple Map), you should change your protocol for maps.

Like:

```
maps://maps.apple.com/?q={latitude},{longitude}
```

Now http://maps.apple.com query will redirect to google map :O

Answer (score 8):

I use this url format:

http://maps.apple.com/?ll={lat},{long}&z={zoom}&q={label+name}

The url opens the internal maps app in the position indicated with a marker that shows a label with the text indicated in querystring

Answer (score 2):

Append '**q**' param to url for add marker on iOS map app

Check below link

> http://maps.apple.com/?q={location_name}&ll={latitude},{longitude}

or

> http://maps.apple.com/?q={lat},{longitude}&ll={latitude},{longitude}