# Open Apple Maps by passing latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, cordova, apple-maps

I am trying to open Apple Maps in my PhoneGap app when a user clicks on a link. The URL scheme in Apple's documentation is like `http://maps.apple.com/maps?ll=51.83733,-8.3016`, which opens Apple Maps if it is present, else redirects to Google Maps. But when I click on this link, it opens Google Maps Web App instead, and there is no way to go back to the app.

Searching for a solution, I found this SO question - [Phonegap - Open Navigation Directions in Apple Maps App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503551/phonegap-open-navigation-directions-in-apple-maps-app)
It suggests using `maps:` instead of `http://maps.apple.com/?q=somePlaceName`. This works fine and opens the native Apple Maps app. But I want to pass latitude and longitude instead of a place name.

I tried with `maps?ll:51.84,-8.30`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this question really have anything to do with google-maps?

Comment: PhoneGap opens up the Google Maps web view. And also, i have edited the question too many times to add a tag for PhoneGap and also to move the `corodva` tag in front, but it gets removed automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) plugin to your project and open the link with the system web browser, which will automatically redirect to Apple Maps:

```
var mapLocationUrl = 'maps.apple.com/?ll=51.84,-8.30';
var ref = window.open(encodeURI(mapLocationUrl), '_system', 'location=no');
```

Check the official [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1) for the complete list of parameters.

Comment: Hi Nair! If you read my question again, I am using the same URL that you have mentioned, but it opens up Mobile Google Maps web app.

Comment: hope u tried exactly as written. I used iOS 6.1 and used inAppBrowser to call browser instance and it automatically redirects to apple map app. See the code 

var mapLocationUrl = 'http://maps.apple.com/?ll=51.84,-8.30';
                                var ref = window.open(encodeURI(mapLocationUrl), '_system', 'location=no');

Comment: @Nair It works fine and opens Apple Maps when I open this page in Safari on my Map. You mean inAppBrowser inside PhoneGap app?

Comment: Yes, use inAppBrowser API in phonegap.

Comment: Hi Nijil, I used inAppBrowser and it worked fine. Please update your answer so I can mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot!