# How do I open Apple Maps App

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps

I have a button. When `touch up inside` it should open Apple Maps for users to navigate to their destination (passed lat long).

The code posted several months ago no longer seems to be valid:

```
var mapLocationUrl = 'maps.apple.com/?ll=51.84,-8.30';
var ref = window.open(encodeURI(mapLocationUrl), '_system', 'location=no');
```

[Open Apple Maps by passing latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447759/open-apple-maps-by-passing-latitude-and-longitude?lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current technique is to make an MKMapItem and call `openInMapsWithLaunchOptions`. The MKMapItem can be made from an MKPlacemark describing the location to be shown.