# Cant launch Map from app on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

I am trying to launch a map from within my app, and I am using the following:

```
- (void) showMap:(id) button {
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *address = [((PhoneButton *) button).cell.client fullAddress];
    NSString *addressUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@", address];
    NSLog(@"Maps String: %@", addressUrl);
    NSURL *map_url = [NSURL URLWithString:addressUrl];
    [application openURL:map_url];
};
```

Well, it is not working. I tried to find the issue but looks like I am doing it right. So, what am I missing?

PS: My address format is like "800, Madison Ave, New York, NY"

Comment: Duplicate of how to open Maps in iOS 6 programatically: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12504294/558933.  This question also has the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Your address format is like

> "800, Madison Ave, New York, NY"

which contain space between words. Remove space with "+" sign. your final URL should be like below URL.
with this you can launch Map from app on iOS 6.

http://maps.apple.com/?q=800,+Madison+Ave,+New+York,+NY

Answer (score 0):

URLs can't have spaces. Spaces and other special characters need to be escaped properly. You want:

```
NSString *escapedAddress = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *addressUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@", escapedAddress];
```