# Programmatically open Maps app in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks, menubar

Is there a way to open OS X (Maverick's) Maps.app from a NSMenuItem?  I'd like to plot a lat/lng pair on Apple Maps.

This will open OpenStreetMaps in a browser:

```
-(IBAction) plot: (id) sender {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.openstreetmap.org/"];
    if( ![[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url] )
        NSLog(@"Failed to open url: %@",[url description]);

}
```

A related topic:

[Programmatically open Maps app in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504294/programmatically-open-maps-app-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Apple's spec here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/IphoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf):

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.apple.com/?ll=45.5200,-122.6819"];
 if( ![[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url] )
      NSLog(@"Failed to open url: %@",[url description]);
```

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, I would do `openUrl:url withApplication:@"Maps"`

Comment: I'm not seeing that method? Just `openURL` and `openFile:withApplication`?

Comment: Hmm you're right. I didn't read it clearly enough. You can do `openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers` however. All the other methods are probably conveniences for that.

Comment: @mackworth, that worked.  Why did it work?  Is Maps.app somehow associated with that URL?  

If this was an older OS, I'm assuming that this would just open a brower, right?

Comment: I kinda hid the reference to Apple's doc, and have made it more explicit.  It goes through all the different scenarios. My guess is Apple sends a redirect from maps.apple.com that causes it to launch an associated URL.  (similar to how itunes is redirected from phobos.apple.com  The docs says that the info for maps was added 2013-09-18, so not sure what older ones would do.

Comment: Not quite, I believe http://maps.apple.com is actually hardcoded to the Maps app in iOS 6+ and OS X 10.9+. What's nice is that maps.apple.com redirects to maps.google.com, so opening URLs like this is backwards-compatible. There's no reason to open the URL with the Maps app specifically.

Answer (score 0):

`open -a Maps.app` will open it from a Terminal.

You could do this in `NSAppleScript` or probably from `Launch Services`

Comment: This is the same as `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspate] openURL:withApplication:]` except much slower.