# Maps not being shown in webview- iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, maps

I have a button in my view. On clicking it leads to a webview in which I want to show the maps. The code I am using is:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSString *url =  [@"http://maps.apple.com/?q=" stringByAppendingString:self.address];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSURLRequest *metricsRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    _webViewForLocation.delegate = self;
    [_webViewForLocation loadRequest:metricsRequest];
    NSLog(@"Maps String: %@", url);
}
```

But the webview is blank. HOw do I show maps in it?

Comment: what the result  u get in this **NSLog(@"Maps String: %@", url);**

Comment: Say, if my self.address is "Bangalore", then i get "http://maps.apple.com/?q=bangalore"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[_webViewForLocation loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?q=bangalore"]]]];  // here pass your string


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

 }



- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

the output is

[image]

refers this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504294/programmatically-open-maps-app-in-ios-6),