# Programmatically launch Apple Maps without directions or a place mark

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios9, apple-maps

After reading this post, [Programmatically open Maps app in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504294/programmatically-open-maps-app-in-ios-6)

using the code below, I launch Apple Maps but I just want to open Apple Maps not send an address, place mark or directions to it.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.180383, -75.229618);
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate
                                               addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mapItem setName:@"Home"];
// Pass the map item to the Maps app
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just use `openURL` with a `http://maps.apple.com` URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in your application to open just Apple Maps

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q="]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use apples URL schemes

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.apple.com"]];
```

For more information please refer to apples maps URL sceme documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html