# Two same Google Maps links work differently in two scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-maps

I got code which generate link to Google Maps by data from form on page.

Example of generated links: "[https://www.google.pl/maps/dir/Düdingen](https://www.google.pl/maps/dir/D%C3%BCdingen), Szwajcaria/6247 Schötz, Szwajcaria/5466 Veghel, Holandia"

Than by window.open() browser open it.

It works correct in all ways.

But, when I'm opening it on iOS at iPad, in one part of code it immediately opens Google Maps App, and in different place on my page it opens in Safari.

**Is there any way to force opening always on Google Maps App?**

Comment: Hi Berkas, are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue to Apple users.
Try this from [cnet site](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/set-google-apps-to-open-by-default-using-chrome-for-ios/).

1.To set Chrome for iOS to launch these apps by default, make sure you install the latest update from the App Store.

2.Once you have it installed, launch the app and tap on the menu icon next to the address bar.

3.Select Settings from the list of options.

4.Tap on Google Apps.

Comment: But I want to launch these links from Safari not Chrome.

Comment: Ok, I thought you said "always  opening Google Maps App".

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on this issue lead me the following conclusions:

If you use `maps.google.com` then it will open the map in `safari` for every IOS.

```
http://maps.google.com/?daddr=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino+CA
```

If you use `maps.apple.com` then it will open the map in map application, it will directly in Apple Maps on an IOS device or redirect to Google Maps otherwise.

```
http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=1600+Amphitheatre+Pkwy,+Mountain+View+CA
```

Here's a related SO ticket: [Programmatically open Maps app in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504294/programmatically-open-maps-app-in-ios-6)